# Visual Studio 2017 drop down menu on "Run" (green arrow) not there

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, configuration, visual-studio-2017

In a tutorial that I'm following, I'm supposed to set a value from a drop down menu that is attached to the *Start Debugging* button.  Here's an image of the drop down:
[image]

Here it is a little closer (note that "Dutch Treat" is the creepy, creepy name of the program in the tutorial):

[image]

And here's what *my* drop down menu looks like:

[image]

It *isn't* a drop down menu!  I've done a lot of customization, so I'm thinking that maybe I customized the drop down menu out of existence.

I really and truly don't want to go back to the default way that the screen is set up.  What I'd like to do is figure out either what the name of the drop down menu is so I can customize it back (using **Tools -> Customize -> Commands** or something similar).

Does anyone know where I can find this drop down in **Customize -> Commands**, or.. well, any way to fix this without going back to the default setup?

The tutorial and my solution have the same configuration:

- Visual Studio 2017
- the project is ASP.NET Core Web Application
- .NET Core
- ASP.NET Core 2.1

---

Update: I haven't solved the problem of "no dropdown", but I did find the correct button.

The green arrow button that I showed on my toolbar is not the same green arrow button as I showed on the tutorial toolbar (good UI!). The one that I had is called "Start/Continue" whereas the one the tutorial had is "Start Debug Target".
[image]

I added the "Start Debug Target" button, and I still didn't get the dropdown.  I'm not sure why.  I'm a complete noob, so I really don't know the difference between *IIS Express*, *DutchTreat* (the name of the program), and Browser names.

However, I think I can continue the tutorial, as it uses *IIS Express* -- so I have that going for me -- but I still don't have the drop down options.  Any sunlight on those options would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try "Start with profiles generation in pause"

Comment: Please elaborate on this answer. I am having the same problem as the original poster but have no idea what you're suggesting I do.